# Why don't I get notifications for new badges I earn?

Tags: bug

For many weeks, I notice I don't get notifications for new badges I earn. I speak about notifications from the StackExchange drop-down at top left:

[image]

When I earn a badge, I don't see the little bubble over by the StackExchange drop-down. From the "Civic Duty" badge, I've earned other badges but nothing appears.

Is anyone knows why? Is it a bug?

Comment: Define "notifications." I haven't seen the big bar across the top of the entire site in some time. But it might be that it was removed, as I do now get a little bubble over by the StackExchange drop-down at top left, for the notifications tab in there.

Comment: I have edited my question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4062/78768

> Most of the bronze badges don't notify users who are considered "veterans" of the network, which is (loosely) defined as having accounts on multiple non-meta sites.
>
> The rationale is that getting a notification everytime you join a new site and, say, downvote gets a tad annoying after a while.
>
> Custodian, being one of the "you did one thing"-bronze badges is one of those who's notifications are suppressed.

Comment: Thanks Stephen. I didn't see this topic.